# Looking for a way where with each commit it can be identify which Unit test case is broken

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I am looking for a solution where with my every CI build on jenkins i can find with which commit how many and which Unit test cases are broken.

So far i have tried [Build Failure Analyzer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer)

But this is not sufficient to get the accurate result.

I am trying the [Jacoco-Comparison-Tool](https://github.com/mariamr/Jacoco-Comparison-Tool). For this there is no Jenkins integration. I am still trying to get a way for this.

Is there any other tools or anything else that can help me to get the UT error/failure reports?

Comment: If your project has tests (Unit tests or non-Unit tests), then using JMeter Plugin in Jenkins you can see per build, what tests failed. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/36601991/jmeterV3.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1260240983000

Comment: That will not tell me who has broken those Uts. And this thing i can check without JMeter also that's why i have sonar which shows me report how many UTs are broken.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has tests (Unit tests or non-Unit tests), then using **JMeter** Plugin in Jenkins you can see per build, what all tests passed/failed. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/36601991/jmeterV3.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1260240983000

In Jenkins there's a  **Test Results Analyzer** plugin which also provides some sort of comparison side by side (at class/package level) for N no. of builds with nice charts but it's basically top level info (i.e. it just shows whether this/that test passed/failed in Green/Red color).

There are other plugins (**XUnit** plugin) that you can try. Also, if you are using SonarQube (analyzing and publishing your tests/results) one can see what happened between two builds (whether the builds failed/passed and to what %).

Comment: Nope this is not what i m looking for.I guess you didn't understand my requirement properly